# Equivalent of Angular 2's service in Vue 2

Tags: angular, vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting my hands dirty at Vue 2 and trying to relate how it compares with Vue 2.

In Angular 2 I would have service and inject it inside `Providers` so service would have a single instance. I would write API calls inside my service calls.

Where would I write the service calls in Vue 2 project so I don't have to copy paste my API calls everywhere?

Thank you.

Comment: In a normal JavaScript module - you can require it anywhere in your application and you'll always get the same instance (this does require you to be using a module bundler like Webpack or Browserify).

Comment: @Joe: I am using webpack. Is it possible to share some link where I can see this example or possibly share some code in your example?

Comment: Basically, when you `import` something (or `require`, if you're still using the old syntax), the source of the module you're importing gets run, and the exports are cached. Then, if you then import the same file elsewhere, you get the same instance of the thing that was exported - the file doesn't get run again. For example, when you import `Vue`, the entirety of Vue's source doesn't get re-run - you just get the same instance of the `Vue` object. This means you can basically use JavaScript modules as a really basic kind of singleton, which in a lot of cases will do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways:

1. Stateless service: then you should use **mixins**
2. Statefull service: use **Vuex**
3. Export service and import from a vue code
   any javascript **global object**

Comment: Isn't Vuex highly constrained and opinionated? I can't for example take a large TypeScript class from most other projects and throw it into Vue as a statefull service with Vuex? I could be wrong though, I'm relatively new to Vue.